# android.os.RemoteException: HwBinder Error: (-32)

Tags: android

I have met a HIDL problem(HwBinder Error: (-32)), when I want to add a HIDL interface to do something, could anybody help?

```
01-29 15:51:02.197042   914  1169 W System.err: android.os.RemoteException: HwBinder Error: (-32)
01-29 15:51:02.197353   914  1169 W System.err:     at android.os.HwRemoteBinder.transact(Native Method)
01-29 15:51:02.197473   914  1169 W System.err:     at vendor.hardware.wifiap.V1_0.IWifiAp$Proxy.doMtkIntCommand(IWifiAp.java:206)
01-29 15:51:02.197581   914  1169 W System.err:     at com.android.server.wifi.WifiVendorHal.doMtkIntCommand(WifiVendorHal.java:2645)
01-29 15:51:02.197682   914  1169 W System.err:     at com.android.server.wifi.WifiNative.doMtkIntCommand(WifiNative.java:1741) 
01-29 15:51:02.197784   914  1169 W System.err:     at com.android.server.wifi.WifiStateMachine$SupplicantStartedState.processMessage(WifiStateMachine.java:4699)
01-29 15:51:02.197900   914  1169 W System.err:     at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:992)
01-29 15:51:02.197999   914  1169 W System.err:     at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:809)
01-29 15:51:02.198097   914  1169 W System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
01-29 15:51:02.198195   914  1169 W System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
01-29 15:51:02.198296   914  1169 W System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding some new method/interface or making changes to existing interface, you need to define the new hidl interface in .hal file. If you are adding the HIDL interface, you need to update the hidl interface also. Be it minor up-rev or major depending on your requirements.

https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/versioning

https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/interfaces

Also, can you please clearly specify, that what exactly do you want to do? It would help us to understand your error more clearly.